# C#: LINQ to SQL Tutorial on youtube.com - Bindings Issue

Tags: linq-to-sql, binding

I don't know if anyone has watched the "Visual Studio 2008, Linq to SQL, C#, and WPF" 21 part tutorial on youtube.com, but I was going through the tutorial and got to the part that I added a datagrid to my WPF.   I have SQL Express where I had manually created a database with tables.  In the program we created a database connection to the database as well as a dataset to its tables.

However, I noticed that when the person giving that tutorial added a datagrid to their WPF, it automatically placed a "my" in front of the element "Datagrid".
Example:

```
 <my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ............/>
```

However, mine is:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ............../>
```

I don't know how much this affects the progrm if any, but the problem that I encountered was when I am trying to add Bindings to some  Elements,

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Student ID" Binding="(Binding Path=StudentID)" />
```

It doesn't appear to be working correctly for the simple fact that the text coloring is not displaying as I would expect and if I misspell "Path" or "StudentID" it doesn't compute an error or change in anyway.  StudentID is the Primary Key of the "Student" table I have created in a DB called "SchoolSystem".

I am new to C# and LINQ to SQL so any advice would be appreciated.

I did try to reach out to the creator of the video's but unsuccessfully so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was that I was using a () instead of {}.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Student ID" Binding="{Binding Path=StudentID}" />
```

or

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Student ID" Binding="{Binding StudentID}" />
```

Depending on how the ItemsSource was bound to the DataGrid.  Also notice you were using parenthesis () instead of curly braces {} in the Binding.

Comment: If that worked, then it would be appropriate to Upvote the answer and mark it as answered.